# Only include certain components of JQuery into webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

### Is it possible just to add certain components of the jQuery library instead of the whole library?

In jQuery UI for example, I found a working solution

```
npm install jquery-ui
```

and the use the components like this

```
/* JQueryUI Draggable */
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js');
```

Is there a similar system that actually works for jQuery itself?

a Typescript solution would be fine too.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to recreate the draggable library without jQueryUI?

Comment: as the title says, im trying to include only the components I need into the project, not the whole jQuery library

Comment: Again, that's not clear. Do you mean 'not the whole jQuery***UI*** library'? You need jQuery at a minimum.

Comment: I mean jQuery when I say jQuery

Comment: Then the answer is no.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot @Rory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! jQuery is available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

As well as Typescript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

Comment: I'm already using that package, but now how do I only include certain components I need instead of the whole thing

Comment: @user3531149 are you using webpack?